# Port Forwarding: Internal Port? Where can I find the Internal Port?

Tags: port-forwarding, port

I wanna create a new Port forwarding, but i dont know my Internal Port... Can someone please help me with that? Where do I have to look?

Comment: What application are you trying to port forward to?

Comment: Remote Desktop... Im using Windows Server 2016 I mean the intern Remote desktop connection by Microsoft

Comment: [rdp - What port should I open to allow remote desktop? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/12005/what-port-should-i-open-to-allow-remote-desktop)

Comment: So its 3398??? I guess yes. Because i already set up everything. Thanks m8

Comment: Your question is currently nonsense.  Please [edit] it (the title ***and*** the body) to say what application you are trying to port forward to.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the Remote Desktop server listens on TCP and UDP ports 3389.
The TCP port may be enough by itself, but by using both you may get better results.

It is possible to change the port used by the terminal server (or PC which is accessed)
by registry update. See this Microsoft support article: [Change the listening port for Remote Desktop on your computer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/change-listening-port).